# Why doesn't Rails autoload classes from app/services?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoload, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm working on a Rails 4.2 app and have just added `app/services/fetch_artists.rb` to the structure. Inside this file, I have defined a `class FetchArtists; end`.

When trying to run `rails r 'FetchArtists'` it gives me a `NameError: uninitialized constant FetchArtists`.

I've tried looking at `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` and indeed, `app/services` is not there:

```
/.../app/assets
/.../app/controllers
/.../app/helpers
/.../app/jobs
/.../app/mailers
/.../app/models
/.../app/controllers/concerns
/.../app/models/concerns
/.../spec/mailers/previews
```

My question is, why isn't this folder automatically loaded, and what should I do for it to be?

**EDIT**

Very strange, after repeatedly running the above command with `rails runner`, the new folder appears on the autoload paths. I have no idea why this happened with such a lag.

Someone suggested this may deal with `spring`. I would like to hear more on this, since it can possibly help many others in this situation too.

Comment: Also, maybe this answer might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44976513/7672657

Answer (score 125):

I encountered the same problem and it seems to be a caching issue with Spring, a process which handles preloading your app. It's used for the web server as well as the console and Rake tasks.

Stopping Spring with `bin/spring stop` will force Spring to load your app fresh. Now running `rails console` and inspecting `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` will successfully show `app/services`.

Comment: Also, naming matters, see this >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547441/gettitng-uninitialized-constant-when-tryhing-to-invoke-my-service-in-rails

Comment: I wonder if this spring isssue will ever bite in production. Specially heroku where i don't know if we can restart spring

Comment: Likely not as you'll have added, committed and deployed your new files.  Spring will not be running on the Heroku instance that is spun up for you latest deploy.

Answer (score 28):

In my case spring was not watching the `app/services` directory for changes - restarting Spring would load the class but changes to an existing class or new class would require a restart of Spring for them to apply.

To resolve this issue I added it to the list of directories watched by Spring in `config/spring.rb`:

```
%w(
  .ruby-version
  .rbenv-vars
  tmp/restart.txt
  tmp/caching-dev.txt
  app/services
).each { |path| Spring.watch(path) }
```

and restarted Spring one more time.

Answer (score 15):

I was having the same problem, and found no solution. I'm not patient enough to wait for autoload to load it eventually, so my quick solution was to turn eager_load on, and start my server. It will finally load it. I switched it off afterwards and my classes were still loaded.

Just use: 
`config.eager_load = true`

in your `config/environments/development.rb`

Answer (score 14):

I came with a similar problem, and took a quick glance at the Spring docs and found this bit about [watchers](https://github.com/rails/spring#watching-files-and-directories).

I added the following to my application.rb and things fell into place -

```
Spring.watch "app/services/**"
```

I'm no expert here, ymmv.

Answer (score -4):

You should include it into `autoload_paths`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/app/services)
```

Comment: From what I've understood, everything directly under `app` is automatically loaded: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths

Comment: @AndreiHorak I've also noticed this. Are you using standard Rails (not Rails-api e.g.)?

Comment: @AndreiHorak i am under the impression that you have to restart the server for the new DIR to be added to the load path...

Comment: @JoelL actually he tried from command line. So it's probably related to spring.

Comment: Yes, I was trying both from `rails runner` and `rails console`. So you may be right, it may come from spring. An answer related to this may be useful for others too, so I'm curious what was spring's involvement in this.

Comment: Stopping Spring with `bin/spring stop` worked for me and allowed the `app/services` directory to be picked up automatically on next app start. You can confirm the autoload paths from the rails console by examining `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths`.