# Getting "uninitialized constant" when trying to invoke my service in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, service, uninitialized-constant

I'm using Rails 4.2.3.  I have this line in a controller:

```
service = XACTEService.new(“Event”, '2015-06-01', 'Zoo')
```

The class in question is defined in app/services/XACTEService.rb.  However upon visiting my controller, I get the error:

```
uninitialized constant MyObjectsController::XACTEService
```

However, I have added this into my config/application.rb file

```
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/services)
```

So I don’t understand why the controller is failing to find my service.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rename this file:

```
app/services/XACTEService.rb
```

to:

```
app/services/xacte_service.rb
```