# NameError (uninitialized constant ShopsController::ShopService - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, service, controller, nameerror

I am getting this error, don't know why.

```
NameError (uninitialized constant ShopsController::ShopService
```

My controller name is *ShopsController* I've made a service `/app/services/shop_service.rb`
The name of the class inside the service is `ShopService`
I'm using it inside a controller action the following way:

```
flag = ShopService.new.save_categories(@shop, params[:category])
```

The service code is written below

```
class ShopService  
  def initialize(shop = nil, services = nil); end
  def save_categories(shop, services)
    debugger
    flag = true
    services.drop(1).each do |service|
      category = Category.new(service: service, shop_id: shop.id)
      flag = false unless category.save
    end
    flag
  end
end
```

Comment: As the error points out `ShopService` is not defined inside the `ShopsController` namespace. Maybe just calling `ShopService` with the global namespace solves the issue. Try changeing `ShopService.new` to `::ShopService.new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call the service like that: `flag = ::ShopService.new.save_categories(@shop, params[:category])` on the controller, this should work

Edit:

Also, check that you are loading the services path in the `config/application.rb`, on the `config.autoload_paths`

Comment: `NameError (uninitialized constant ShopService):`
Got this error now

Comment: Humm can you double check the file name and the class name.
See to if you loading the `services` path on the `config/application.rb`, on the `config.autoload_paths`

Comment: Yes, that was the issue exactly. Thanks. I used the following link to add services to `autoload_paths`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32873343/why-doesnt-rails-autoload-classes-from-app-services